# How to detect "last" back press?

Tags: android

I have an `Activity` with `Fragment`, and there is a lot of transactions, so the back button most often just roll back `Fragment transaction`. But I need to detect the last back press.

I can't use `onPause` method, because I don't want to do anything when the user presses home, or starts another activity.

Comment: Over Ride  onback press in ACtivity as well as in Fragments .... then you can use Static Global variable , Sharedprefrence to save last back press

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use this **getFragmentCount** method below.

It will return the `Fragment` count if it is `0` then your are in last back press

```
private int getFragmentCount() {
    return getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
}
```

call this method in your `onBackPressed()` of your `Activity`

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this helps, but here is the code to catch if the backbutton was pressed:

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        if(keyCode ==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
        {
            //Do stuff here
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```